# IEEE-754 32 Bit (single precision) exponent -126 instead of -127

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

I know if I have a number like that:

```
1 | 1001 0001 | 0011 0011 0000 0001 0101   000 
1 sign bit | 8 bit biased exponent | 23 bit fraction/mantissa
```

I can calculate the "real" exponent by subtraction the bias 127 (0111 1111) from biased exponent. I.e. 1001 0001 - 0111 1111 = 10010 (so real Exponent is 18)

1,0011 0011 0000 0001 0101 000 * 2^18

So now my question:

If a have a (denormalized) number like that:

```
0 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000   001
```

Why the Exponent is -126 and not -127? 0000 0000 - 0111 1111 should be -127 and not -126 so that

0,0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 * 2^-126 and not 0,0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 * 2^-127

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 3):

A denormalized single precision float has an implicit exponent of 2<sup>-126</sup>:

(−1)<sup>signbit</sup>×2<sup>−126</sup>× 0.significandbits

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format for more details.

Comment: But why -126 and not -127

Comment: @knowledge So there's no gap between normals and non-normals.  The smallest normalized value has an exponent value of 1 which translates to 2^-126 and has an implied leading 1 in the significand.  So the value is  2^-126 * 1.0 The largest non-normal has an implied leading 0 in the significand and has a value of 2^-126 * 0.11111111111111111111111.