# Why does the exponent IEEE754 (single) limit between 2^{-126}<= e <=2^{127}?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

I am referring to this question but I'm not satisfied with the answer: [IEEE-754 32 Bit (single precision) exponent -126 instead of -127](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46732247/ieee-754-32-bit-single-precision-exponent-126-instead-of-127)

Does the answer imply that actually the exponent can be [image] but because of the representation in denormalized form the smallest possitive number is [image: $1\cdot2^{-127}\cdot1.\cdots$] equal to [image: $1\cdot2^{-126}\cdot0.1\cdots$].

Does this mean than that the smallest representable positive number is:

[image] or [image: $1\cdot2^{-126}0.1(21\cdot0)1$]

Which of the last two options?

Thank you very much in advance.

Thank you again to everyone, you all gave great explanations!

Comment: Do you want the smallest exactly representable _normal_ positive number (which is `2^{-126}`), or the smallest exactly representable positive number (which is `2^{-149}`)? (Neither of these is equal to either of the two options you give.)

Comment: I was primarily interested in the smallest representable positive number but I also take the exactly representable number. If you could provide me explanations why my suggestions for the smallest positive number are wrong/impossible I would be even more grateful. I always thought the exponent is computed by e-127 and e has 8 bits what leads to a minimum of -127. Why is only -126 ([00000001]_2) possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the exponent IEEE754 (single) limit between 2^{-126}<= e <=2^{127}?
>   Reworded:
>   Why does the exponent IEEE754 (single) limit between -126 <= exponent <= 127?

[binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) has an 8-bit *biased exponent* field allowing for 256 values.  A wider/smaller exponent field could have been selected, yet it is 8 here.  2 values, 0 and 255, have special meaning leaving 254.

In 1970s, it was concluded to symmetrically distribute these *biased exponent* values +/- about zero leading to the 254 values -126 to +127 by employing a 127 offset.

*Normal* values have a form of: sign * (1.xxx... total 23 x's...xxx) * 2<sup>exponent - offset</sup> providing a 24-bit binary precision.

For various numerical computational reasons (after much debate), it was concluded that |values| less than the smallest normal positive number 1.0 * 2<sup>1 - 127</sup> should have a gradual loss of precision.  These are *sub-normal* or [denormal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number) numbers.  They are encoded with a *biased exponent* of 0 and **with the same resultant exponent of -126** as the smallest *normal* number.

```
         v--------------------------------------- Implied valued              
         | v--------------------------v---------- Significant explicitly encoded
         | |                          |     v---- Biased exponent
         | |                          |     | v-v Implied offset  
2^-126 = 1.000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 * 2^1-127 // smallest normal
         0.111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 * 2^0-126 // largest sub-normal
2^-127 = 0.100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 * 2^0-126
2^-128 = 0.010 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 * 2^0-126
2^-129 = 0.001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 * 2^0-126
...
2^-149 = 0.000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 * 2^0-126 // smallest sub-normal
0.0f   = 0.000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 * 2^0-126 // zero
```

So values down to 2<sup>-127</sup> have 24-bit precision and values down to 2<sup>-149</sup> have ever decreasing precision.

Answer (score 2):

In IEEE-754 basic 32-bit binary floating-point, every finite value has the form:

> ± x.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx • 2<sup>*e*</sup>

where x.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx is a binary numeral and −126 ≤ *e* ≤ +127.

For normal numbers, the first x is 1, and *e* may be any value in −126 ≤ *e* ≤ +127. Since the first x is always 1, it is not explicitly stored—the floating-point format contains one bit for the sign, 23 bits for the other x's, and 8 bits for the exponent. The exponent is stored as the binary for *e*+127. So, for *e* from −126 to +127, the stored value is 1 to 254. That leaves 0 and 255.

0 in the exponent field is a code for subnormal numbers. For subnormal numbers, the exponent *e* is the same as the lowest normal exponent, −126, but the first x is 0. So a subnormal value has the form:

> ± 0.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx • 2<sup>−126</sup>

Thus the smallest positive value that can be represented is:

> + 0.00000000000000000000001 • 2<sup>−126</sup>

which is 2<sup>−149</sup>.

(255 in the exponent field is used to represent infinity and NaNs.)

Answer (score 1):

It is quite simple: -126 was chosen for denormals so there is no step between the smallest normal and the largest denormal.

The lowest normal is

> 1.0000...<sub>bin</sub> × 2<sup>-126</sup>

One "ULP" below that is

> 0.1111...<sub>bin</sub> × 2<sup>-126</sup>

If it were 2<sup>-127</sup>, there would be a step of several "ULP" (or even many "ULP") between those two values.

Comment: Thank you, could you also explain the difference between a normal and a denormal in terms of IEEE754 single? (Will probably be back online on tuesday)

Comment: @baxbear: That was for single precision. For a double, the exponents are different, but follow the same principle: -1022..1023 (IIRC) fr normals, and -1022 for denormals too.

Comment: @baxbear: or was your question: what is the difference between normals and denormals? Well, at some point, to "go smaller", you can't decrement the exponent anymore, so you start removing bits from the significand. First, you remove the top bit, the one before the binary point, and then you start counting down (with 23 bits). Normal numbers must have the `1.` bit, so if you remove it, the number is not normal anymore: denormal (they could also have called them anormal or abnormal, I guess). The more leading bits you remove, the less significant bits remain, so you slowly lose precision.